# OSX keyboard shortcuts call a specific function within the script

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I work with Photoshop javascript.
Can OSX keyboard shortcuts call a specific function within the script?

The idea is to have one script that works with multiple keyboard shortcuts.

For example:

- layermask-1.jsx
- newLayer(){};
- addMask(){};
- invertMask(){};
- previewMask(){};
- deleteMask(){}

=====================

- F19 calls function newLayer(){};
- Cmd+F19 calls addMask(){};
- option+cmd+F19 calls invertMask(){};
- control+option+cmd+F19 calls function previewMask(){};
- shit+control+option+cmd+F19 calls  deleteMask(){};